# Update single column in 2-D array

Tags: javascript, date, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-dimensional array like below. The first column is a date and I would like to store it as a number of milliseconds using the `getTime()` function so that I can use it for date comparisons later. Is there an easy way to update a single column in a 2-d array? The original array could have multiple columns.
I'm trying to update the date column here which is the first column. So for example, instead of `Mon Aug 10 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2020`, it should have value returned by `getTime()` on the date object represented by `Mon Aug 10 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2020`

```
 [[Mon Aug 10 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2020, 7.7107286E7, A-Plus Restoration], 
[Sun Feb 09 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2020, 7.1324511E7, Kwik-E-Mart Industries], 
[Sun Mar 08 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2020, 7.5233927E7, Jacob Tannenbaum], 
[Wed Mar 25 23:00:00 GMT-06:00 2020, 7.7678662E7, Music Depot]]
```

Comment: What is this number `7.7107286E7`?

Comment: What column are you trying to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
someData.map((data) => 
  [
     data[0].getTime(), // Does the transformation for column 1
     ...data.slice(1)   // Picks all columns except one and spreads them out
  ]
)
```

Comment: `data[0]` needs to be converted to a date object first.

Comment: From the copy-pasta in the question, it seems to be from a console.log. Try running this in your console: `[new Date, "a", 111.666]` . The assumption is that the element in question is already a date object.

Comment: the format of the copy/paste implies it's a string though. `[ 2020-10-26T07:07:40.670Z, 'a', 111.666 ]` vs `[Wed Mar 25 23:00:00 GMT-06:00 2020, 7.7678662E7, Music Depot]` --- Unless it's browser console, I suppose